# Link rewrite to https (NOT URL rewrite)

Tags: links, https

Client is running WordPress 3.9 on a Mac OS X Server install. We want the site to be responsive to both http and https requests. Luckily, OS X Server has a nifty feature where we can just set up a https instance for the domain, point it at the same folder, and away we go.

The problem is that while most of the links on the site default to https when https is used in the requested URL, *some* of the links are hard-coded to http, so if someone clicks on those links, they'll be taken out of the secure site. Better yet, links to external sites may *have* to be http -- but we want all internal links to stick with https when that's the incoming request.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this? Am I looking at hacking the links database? A plugin? I'm aware of the various https plugins, but we don't need anything that affects *serving* https -- that's already being handled by Apache and OS X Server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Redirect all URL–matching http to https on Apache level?.. WP doesn't even have to come into play here. Why do you want to keep http working at all if you have secure version?

Comment: We don't want to *force* https. IF someone comes in over http, that's fine to leave them there. We just don't want to redirect someone coming in over https back to http. As for "why" -- client says so. :-)

Comment: Not an answer to your question but something to consider... Google has stated they will begin using more security signals as ranking factors (https will be favorable to http) so why not let it all run securely?  My team is actually considering a shift to do all future site projects 100% https all the time.

Comment: Ahh- client says so then it's up to you to make it so, unless a little more explanation or education could sway their opinion.